# How to get Facebook post id when uploading?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have created a custom desktop app (Adobe AIR) that allows users to upload videos and pictures to their wall. As it turns out, I have to have control of these posts that get created by my app. I've read that everything you post using graph api has a post id:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

I would like to know how can I retrieve this id so I can keep track of certain statistics later with FQL. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: see what your code returns after successfully posting the photo.Facebook returns the postId after posting the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating a post or uploading a photo to Facebook, the id of the newly created object is returned by Facebook. What you need to do is to fetch the response of the POST request you sent.

This should help https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

If you know C#.Net coding i shall provide you sample code for implementing it.

Get back if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

When you press on the timestamp in the head of the post you'll get a page with the post only with it's link in the adress bar, there you can also see the post ID.
That was what I've been looking for, and found out by myself...
Hope it helped you too.